# CommandLine.arguments not the latest

Tags: swift

I'm writing an app that process CLI arguments (from Commandlne.arguments).
The app is launched using the [tidevice](https://github.com/alibaba/tidevice) tool.
e.g.

```
tidevice -u xxx launch x.x.x.x -- arg1 arg2 ...
```

The problem is that:

- on iOS 12, every time I use this command, I always get the latest CLI arguments.
- However, on iOS 16, I always get the CLI arguments that the app receives when first launched.

What's wrong with my app? Or is it the expected behavior on iOS 16?